# convert matlab null space to c#

Tags: c#, matlab

I am at the moment converting some code form matlab to C#.

I have:

```
A = [0;0;1];
B = null(A); 

B returns :
0   -1
1    0
0    0
```

I have tried to read about the null function in matlab, but I dont really understand how it works and how to do something similar in c#.

I hope somebody can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I'd suggest to start by [reading the documentation on `null()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html), and explaining what you don't understand about that, as it's quite clearly written, as well in terms of MATLAB, as in terms of mathematics. Especially the latter shouldn't be too difficult to translate.

Comment: Hi Adriaan, I have read the docs of course - but I dont understand the mathematics enough to make an equivalent function in C#.

Comment: You dont have to do everything yourself, I am quite sure that someone else already programmed a linear equation solver in C#. Try to google that ...